# How does the Reddit Alien animation on the mobile app work?

Tags: html, css, jquery, mobile

Does any one know How the Reddit Alien animation on the mobile app work. This animation changes with the loading time.

IS this done through Ajax calls to change images after a certain time has elapsed?

Answer (score 1):

The picture of Snoo is added in `fetch_more()` in [mobile.js](http://www.redditstatic.com/mobile.js):

```
function fetch_more()
{
    $("#siteTable").after($("<div class='loading'><img src='" + r.utils.staticURL("reddit_loading.png") + "'/></div>"));
    var a = document.location,
        c = a.pathname.split("."),
        c = c[c.length - 1].indexOf("/") == -1 ? c.slice(0, -1).join(".") : a.pathname,
        a = a.protocol + "//" + a.host + c + ".json-compact" + a.search,
        c = $("#siteTable").find(".thing:last");
    a += (document.location.search ? "&" : "?") + "after=" + c.thing_id();
    c.find(".rank").length && parseInt(c.find(".rank").html());
    $.getJSON(a, function (a)
    {
        $.insert_things(a.data, !0);
        $(".thing").click(function ()
        {});
        $("#siteTable").next(".loading").remove();
        a && a.data.length == 0 && $(window).unbind("scroll")
    })
};
```

The actual animation is done in [compact.css](http://www.redditstatic.com/compact.css) (through the `.loading` class of the parent `div`):

```
.loading img {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotateThis;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Both files are heavily compacted, so the code snippets above were taken from versions prettified using tools found through google.

Comment: Thanks, Could someone please do a JSfiddle for this? I'd like to do it on a web page. Cheers

Comment: @user2599381 http://jsfiddle.net/gKvmJ/2/ - I've added all the required parts, with a `setTimeout`.  You'll need to hack it around to fit how you want it to. (Note this is my first time playing with JSFiddle, so YMMV.)